# Marginal probability problem

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random value with a distinct uniform distribution in range $i=1,2,...,n$

Let $Y|X=i$ be a random value with a distinct uniform distribution in range $j=1,2,...,2i$

In order to find the marginal probability of $Y$, we need to sum over all possibilities of $i$ the probability of $Y|X=i$. Therefore:

$P\{Y\}=\cfrac{n}{2i}$ But since $i$ ranges from $1$ to $n$: $P\{Y\}=\cfrac{n}{2n}=\cfrac{1}{2}$

I'm not sure about the last statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $P(Y=j\mid X=i)$ can only take positive values if $2i\geq j$ or equivalently $i\geq\lceil\frac12j\rceil$.

Applying the law of total probability we find for $j\in\{1,2,\dots,2n\}$:

$$P(Y=j)=\sum_{i=1}^nP(Y=j\mid X=i)P(X=i)=\frac1n\sum_{i\geq\lceil\frac12j\rceil}^n\frac1{2i}$$